# Button with additional parameters (NOT ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I have a button to filter search result to nearest location.

my html button

```
<a href="trending" onclick="addUrl(this); alert(this);" class="btn btn-warning" id="location">Nearest Location</a>
```

my jquery

```
function addUrl(element){
    if(navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
            var lat = position.coords.latitude;
            var lng = position.coords.longitude;
            console.log(lat);
            console.log(lng);

            $(element).attr('href',function(){
                return element.href + '?lat=' + lat + '&lng=' + lng;
            });


        });
    }

    else
        alert("navigator.geolocation is not available");
}
```

When I click the button, it seems navigate to the url without parameter. Not sure whats wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `geolocation.getCurrentPosition` function is asynchronous so actually your code changes `href` attribute after redirect actions is performed. You can disable default link click action (use `e.preventDefault()` or `return false` inside click event handler) and inside `geolocation.getCurrentPosition` callback use `window.location.href = YOUR_URL_WITH_PARAMS` which will cause redirection.

```
document.getElementById('location').addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = e.target.href;
    addUrl(href);
});

function addUrl(href){
    if(navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
            var lat = position.coords.latitude;
            var lng = position.coords.longitude;
            console.log(lat);
            console.log(lng);
            window.location.href = href + '?lat=' + lat + '&lng=' + lng;


        });
    }

    else
        alert("navigator.geolocation is not available");

}
```

Comment: how do I navigate to the page with newly added parameter if using preventDefault()?

Comment: As I mentioned using `window.location.href = YOUR_URL_WITH_PARAMS` - setting this makes redirect. You can read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location

Comment: Glad I could help :) I will be thanful for marking this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your 'onclick' event inside html document, you can use event listener and call preventDefault() function for stopping native events.
Sample:

```
document.getElementById('location').addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    addUrl(this);
});
```

addUrl function:

```
function addUrl(element){
    if(navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
            var lat = position.coords.latitude;
            var lng = position.coords.longitude;
            console.log(lat);
            console.log(lng);

            window.location.href = $(element).attr("href") + '?lat=' + lat + '&lng=' + lng;
        });
    }

    else
        alert("navigator.geolocation is not available");
}
```

Comment: how do I navigate to the page with newly added parameter if using preventDefault()?

Comment: You want to execute your function first, and after that navigate to 'trending'. Am I right?

Comment: I'm edited my solution. Basically, you can just set window.location.href property and that's it.